# Git push hook to disable push to branch

Tags: git, continuous-integration, workflow, branch, hook

We need to prevent pushing to some branch on our bitbucket repo.

And we think that it will be ok for us to prevent it locally.

Is there any way to prevent pushing to some branch locally via some pre-push hook?

OS: Windows.

Comment: Is there a special reason you want to add a client side hook rather than a server side one?

Comment: Any server side solution for bitbucket? Disable push but enable merge via pull-request.

Comment: Ah sry, I didn't notice you were using a bitbucket repository. I'll try to find a solution for the client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is obviously a suboptimal solution, but since BitBucket doesn't provide a possibility to add an update hook I will provide it anyway.

To prevent pushing to a branch via a local hook you can use the `pre-push` hook (available since git 1.8.2).

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
     if [ "$remote_ref" = "refs/heads/test" ]; then
        echo "Pushing to branch \"test\" is forbidden"
        exit 1
     fi
done

exit 0
```

Just replace `test` with the corresponding branch name you want to protect from pushs.

For more information on the pre-push hook you can take a look at the [example file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/87c86dd14abe8db7d00b0df5661ef8cf147a72a3/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample), and if you want to learn more about hooks in general you can read the [corresponding chapter in the gitpro book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

---

**IMPORTANT**

Remember that you have to install this hook in every clone of the repository, since it's a client side hook rather than a server side one.

Obviously a server side `update` hook would be preferable.