# Is there a way to prevent myself pushing locally to remote master, like the way Github can prevent pushing to master?

Tags: git, github

I want to turn on locally for myself a protection that stops me accidentally pushing to master (or any branch in particular).

Github can allow blocking pushing to master but I want to have that locally for companies or repos that do not have the protection.

It's a tricky question for a search engine too, because there's so many other git related questions out there, I thought here was the best place to ask.

Comment: @matt There is also the `pre-push` hook.

Comment: "*It's a tricky question for a search engine…*" Nothing tricky. Just search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+prevent+pushing+locally and find https://stackoverflow.com/a/24695953/7976758

Comment: thanks! i ddin't see any of these in my Google bubble

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`pre-push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) hook.
This hook is a client-side hook that is called whenever you try to push some commits on a remote repo. Basically it is an executable file called `pre-push` that you must create in the folder `.git/hooks/`. It receives the remote name and the url of the remote as parameters, while on the stdin it receives a line (or more) in this form:

```
<local ref> SP <local object name> SP <remote ref> SP <remote object name> LF
```

> For instance, if the command `git push origin master:foreign` were run the hook would receive a line like the following:

```
refs/heads/master 67890 refs/heads/foreign 12345
```

In your case, the content of the `pre-push` executable could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [ "$remote_ref" = "refs/heads/master" ]
    then
        echo "You cannot push to master"
        exit 1
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a way that doesn't involve mucking with hooks: In your `.git/config` you can set up a separate remote for pushing to your branch ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtpushRemote)). If you set that to a nonexisting remote:

```
[branch "main"]
        remote = origin
        pushRemote = no-push-to-main
        merge = refs/heads/main
```

then `git push` on that branch will fail:

```
$ git push
fatal: 'no-push-to-main' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The error message can be confusing so it's a good idea to pick a helpful name for your fake remote.