# How do I disable pushing a specific branche's code in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I want to keep my repositories clean with only the necessary number of branches, which is just a master branch and sometimes additional feature or hotfix branches that are being worked on.

However, I sometimes like to branch out locally from master to test some things out for myself. I want to make sure I don't ever push these branches to the repository because I don't want to confuse other members on my team since they don't need to see these branches.

Is there a setting in Visual Studio to prevent pushing changes in a branch and only allow local commits? I use Git.

Comment: There is the `pre-push` hook that I think you might use to keep git from pushing stuff.... run some checks, if it's not one of the branches you allow to push, reject it. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24695953/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+disable+push+branch

Comment: Forgot to mention that I actually don't use the command-line Git and instead use the Visual Studio UI to do my Git stuff. But I imagine your suggestions may work too. I'll be sure to test and report back.